# Is it a bad idea to have two forms keep an instance of one another?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am a student and I have little to no idea of good programming practices, I have a Visual Basic form which has a DataGirdView, when you click on one of the columns it should open another form (ventanaMod) that lets you edit the data from that specific row.

I have managed to get the program to do what i want using this code.

```
Private Sub dgvNotas_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvNotas.CellDoubleClick
        Dim selectedRow As DataRow
        selectedRow = dgvNotas.DataSource.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim ventanaMod As New Modificar(selectedRow, Me)
        Me.Hide()
        ventanaMod.Show()
End Sub
```

I wanted it to hide and not close and it behaves the way I want it to, but in order to open it again I needed to store the other form as a variable (ventanaOrig)

```
Dim ventanaOrig As Form1

    Public Sub New(registro As DataRow, pventanaOrig As Form1)
        InitializeComponent()
        lblName.Text = registro("Nombre")
        lblApellidos.Text = registro("Apellidos")
        txtCiclo.Text = registro("Ciclo")
        txtCurso.Text = registro("Curso")
        txtVB.Text = registro("Nota1")
        txtAndr.Text = registro("Nota2")
        txtPy.Text = registro("Nota3")
        txtAws.Text = registro("Nota4")
        txtNav.Text = registro("Nota5")
        txtWpf.Text = registro("Nota6")
        txtEmpr.Text = registro("Nota7")
        txtEng.Text = registro("Nota8")
        TxtQV.Text = registro("Nota9")
        ventanaOrig = pventanaOrig
End Sub
```

And this means that I have one instance of my Modify Form in my Main form and one instance of my Main form in my Modify form, I was wondering if this could create any problems and in what other way I could aproach this.

```
Private Sub Modificar_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
        ventanaOrig.Show()
End Sub
```

Also this is the part of my code that uses the instance of the Main form to open it when I close the window

Comment: Please watch your tags - VBA and VB.Net are two different languages.

Comment: It would probably be better to have both forms interact with a common model object (or object graph).  Then the "modify" form doesn't need to know about the host form.

Comment: I would say, it's not entirely wrong to have forms linked like this, the risk in my mind is more about the data that is displayed/edited getting out of sync and potential for invalidating it with partial updates.  For that reason, I would be more incline to create a fresh new instance of the edit form each and every time it's needed.

Comment: Sorry I Didn't know it was the wrong tag, I will keep it in mind in the future, thanks.

Comment: I hadn't thought about a common object, that is a good idea, I will try to apply it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be aware of the differences between a [modal dialog box and a modeless dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/modal-and-modeless-dialog-boxes?view=msvc-170)

If your form opens a modal dialog box, the form becomes inactive. You have to fill in the modal dialog box and close it (OK or Cancel), before you can continue working on your form. In windows standard user interface, your form remains visible, but cannot become active. Be aware, that windows users expect this behaviour. A common example of a modal dialog box is the *file - open* dialog box.

If your form opens a modeless dialog box, then both your form and the modeless dialog box can become active. Both forms can be edited, moved, minimized, etc.

If I look at what you want, you want to show a modal dialog box. As an extra, you want to hide your main form while the modal dialog box is visible. Be aware that this is a deviation from standard windows UI. Operators won't expect this, they start to think: hey, where is my application. Also you have to solve the problem if the operator decides to minimize all windows (how to show it again?), or close the application, or close windows. My advice would be: stick to the standard windows UI.

I'm not sure if the dialog box is only used to show information to the operator, or if the operator needs to provide information that must be passed to the main form after the operator indicates he has finished editing (= pressed OK)

My visual basic is very rusty, so I can't give you the VB code. As example I'll show you the C# code. I'm sure you'll get the gist.

```
class ExtraInformation
{
    ... // properties to communicate between your form and the modal dialog box
        // TODO: invent proper class name
}
```

If you only want to show extra information, the operator does not have to enter information in your modal dialog box, use this:

```
void ShowExtraInformation (ExtraInformation extraInformation)
{
    using (MyExtraDialogBox dlg = new MyExtraDialogBox()
    {
        // fill the dialog box with the extraInformation:
        dlg.SetInitialValues(extraInformation);

        // only if you want to deviate from windows standard:
        this.Visible = false;

        // show the dialog box, and wait until closed:
        dlg.ShowDialog(this);   // this: I am the parent window

        // if you hid this form, show it again
        this.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

Of course, you have to create `MyExtraDialogBox.SetInitialValues`. This method will fill all values that must be displayed.

If you want to show extra information, let the operator add some input and use the operator input:

```
class OperatorInput     // TODO: invent proper name
{
    ...
}

OperatorInput GetOperatorInput (ExtraInformation extraInformation)
{
    using (MyExtraDialogBox dlg = new MyExtraDialogBox()
    {
        // fill the dialog box with the extraInformation:
        dlg.SetInitialValues(extraInformation);

        // only if you want to deviate from windows standard:
        this.Visible = false;

        // show the dialog box, and wait until closed:
        DialogResult dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog(this);

        // if you hid this form, show it again
        this.Visible = true;

        OperatorInput operatorInput = dlg.GetOperatorInput();
        return operatorInput;
     }
 }
```

You need a procedure that extracts the ExtraInformation from the selected row and a procedure that processes the operator input:

```
ExtraInformation CreateExtraInformation(DataGridViewRow selectedRow) {...}
void ProcessOperatorInput(OperatorInput operatorInput {...}
```

The implementation is out-of-scope of this question.

```
// TODO: invent a proper method name
void ShowInformationAndProcessOperatorInput(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    // extract the ExtraInformation:
    ExtraInformation extraInformation = this.CreateExtraInformation(row);

    // show the dialog box to show the extraInformation and process the operator input
    OperatorInput operatorInput = this.GetOperatorInput(extraInformation);
    this.ProcessOperatorInput(operatorInput);
}
```

Finally the event handler on cell click is very small:

```
void CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = this.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex);
    ShowInformationAndProcessOperatorInput(selectedRow);
}
```

I created small procedures that have only one task. This way these procedures are easier to understand. They can easily be unit tested. It is easier to reuse them. For example: suppose you want to add a button or menu item that does the same with the currently selected cell as a double click:

```
void OnButtonShowData_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = this.GetSelectedRow();
    ShowInformationAndProcessOperatorInput(selectedRow);  
}
```

Apart from reusability, small changes will hardly affect the rest of the code. For instance, if you want to show a little bit more or less from the selected row, most procedures won't change

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very detailed. I just wanted to hide the original form in order to make it seem like the person had been redirected, but from now on I will adhere to the windows standard. Apart from that, it was very useful and again, thank you for the answer.